# Testdisk isn't copying undeleted files, images provided

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, testdisk

I'm using Linux Mint 17, and I'm trying to recover from an unmounted NTFS external drive.

Testdisk seems to know that there's a deleted file there, but isn't letting me copy it. This is what I'm trying to do.

First, I'm selecting advanced options in testdisk.

Next, I'm selecting the partition and choosing "undelete."

[Press 'c' choosing the only undeleted file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCOzn.png)

Now, I'm pressing 'c' to copy the only undeleted file available.

[Press 'c' to copy to home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVAhy.png)

I'm once again pressing 'c' to copy to the file to my home directory.

Finally, it's just bringing me back to the menu in the first picture, except the pressing 'c' or 'C' doesn't do anything.

I've tried running as normal user and as sudo. I really have no idea what to do at this point and think this might be a bug. I need these files yesterday.

Comment: As far as I remember, you need to copy to a different file system: it won't write anything to the file system with the deletions, as every write reduces the chances of successful recovery.

Comment: The file should be in one of those `recup_dir` directories.